# IPA contains the relative path of my source code in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, security, reverse-engineering, ipa

after exporting IPA, i send it to a security team to test it, and they give me a list of [classes paths of my source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkpnf.png), how can i hide this path from the ipa?

when i use `fatalError("error message ")` function the message that is passed to the function is printed to the console along with the file and line on which the `fatalError(_:file:line:)` function is called. exemple: fatal error: error message: file /Users/Bart/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling/ViewController.swift, line 20 . using "[IDA Starter](https://www.hex-rays.com/)" and decompile the ipa we can find the path of classes that contains fatalError function.

Comment: Did my solution work on your problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your method call to fatalError, and will check is release or not. And will not include file and line info.

```
func myFatalError(_ message: String, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
  #if DEBUG
  fatalError(message, file: file)
  #else
  fatalError(message, file: "", line: 0)
  #endif
}
```

Just call `myFatalError("Message")`

Good luck