# References for CI/CD tool inside iOS .ipa file

Tags: ios, swift, security, reverse-engineering, ipa

the app where I am working on was audited and the security team has a concern that consists in: so, for some reason if I extract the `.ipa`'s payload I am able to identify which CI/CD tool was used to generate it. For example:

Terminal:

```
cd MyApp.app                         <- payload
strings * > ~/Desktop/file.txt
```

Inside the file I can find that we are using jenkins

```
/Volumes/jenkins-workspace/MyApp-Generic/MyApp/MyApp/SomeViewModel.swift
```

Has anyone faced this problem (if we can call it a problem)? Is there a way to obfuscate or completely remove this kind of references from the IPA?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Swift 5.3 introduces a #fileID identifier which produces a shorter
> string than #file. The #fileID string contains the filename and module
> name, but leaves out the rest of the path to the file; this saves
> space, improves performance, and avoids accidentally embedding private
> information like the developer’s home directory name in binaries.
> Compiler-generated error messages (like force-unwraps) and standard
> library assertions like precondition and fatalError now use #fileID
> strings, and we recommend you use them instead of #file in production
> code. (SE-0285, 65514304)

This pretty much sums my problem. I am using the `#file` identifier in some methods (mostly for logs) and every file that calls that methods will appear embedded in the app binary.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-release-notes

Answer (score 1):

Does that file have a fatalError() call in it? If so, the file and line number will be reported when it runs. Here's [a way to fix that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57718843/ipa-contains-the-relative-path-of-my-source-code-in-ios) if you really need the fatalError call.

If any of your source files have #file compiler directives in them, they will record the path to the file in the executable.

Comment: In some files I don't have a `fatalError()` but I do have a lot of logs. Could that be related?